# Массовая печать документов

Tags: печать, принтер

Сталкивался ли кто-то из Вас с реализацией массовой печати архивированных документов? Возможно тут может помочь Windows PrintServer?

**Кейс следующий:**

1. Имеется n архивов с документами (.doc, .pdf, .jpg). В одном архиве может быть 15 документов.
2. Требуется сделать так, чтобы можно было n архивов "отправить" на печать без распаковки всех архивов со стороны пользователя ПК (возможно положить их все в какой-то сетевой каталог, где они будут скриптом/приложением распаковываться и отправляться на печать - шаг 3
3. Документы должны печататься с соблюдением очередности

Как итог, на выходе должно быть 1000-1500 распечатанных страниц

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробовали ли https://www.doc2prn.com/ ?

Там есть возможность использовать скрипты.

На сайте есть документация и примеры

Comment: спасибо, попробуем в деле